# How to get conditional formatting to use the cell date value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I set up conditional formatting with the goal of checking cell dates. The formatting is supposed to gauge and show how quickly a date is coming up to complete a task.

Below is how I set this up. What I did was use TODAY() thinking that would pull the cell value. What it is doing is using the current date instead of the cell date. How do I use the cell's date instead? If the cell value of I12 is 6/3, how does that compare to today? Are we x days before or after?

You can see from the green outlined cells a specific date and then the other green outline represents the date ranges I am after. The 6/3/2021 date should not have any highlighting at all since the date passed.

Any ideas?

UPDATE

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the rest of the second formula? I presume it is `=TODAY()-37`

Comment: Note: `TODAY() - 21` is twenty one days ago, so it would be normal for a past date to be highlighted. Perhaps you want `TODAY() + 21`?

Comment: @EngineerToast You are correct.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad The cell's value should be the nucleus. The highlighted/green outlined cell in the example should not be highlighted at all. I want it to check for 6/3/21 - 21. Maybe having TODAY() in there is completely the wrong move.

Comment: Using the conditional formatting to highlight cells that are between `=TODAY()-21` and `=TODAY()-37` equates to highlighting cells whose value is between 2021-06-08 and 2021-06-24 as of the time I'm writing this. I tried to duplicate your sheet but it doesn't highlight the 2021-06-03 date in [my sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSNy0.png) like it does in yours. The most likely candidate is some other formatting (conditional or otherwise) that's doing it. Try clearing all formatting and adding just this one rule. Does it still highlight it when it shouldn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is compared with the date in the cell, determine whether today is before or after it, please try the following formulas.

[37-21] days before: `=AND(A2-TODAY()>=21,A2-TODAY())<=37`

[20-8] days before: `=AND(A2-TODAY()>=8,A2-TODAY()<=20)`

[7-0] days before: `=AND(A2-TODAY()>=0,A2-TODAY()<=7)`

(0-7] days after: `=AND(A2-TODAY()>=-7,A2-TODAY()<0)`

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Why would A2 constantly be used? Wouldn't that always result in A2 being referenced and not all of the other dates below/above it?

Comment: Let's use the yellow background conditions. 21-37 days before. If the cell value of A2 was 8/15/21, that is when the cell should be turning yellow. It is measuring the cells date and seeing if the current date is that many days beforehand. All of the dates in your example wouldn't show any formatting except the dark red as the dates have already occured and are a week after.

Comment: @Paul I misunderstood the reference date of "before" and "after", and I will change my previous reply. Besides, the cell A2 is a relative reference, not an absolute reference, so for range formulas apply to, the cell will automatically change.

Comment: Thank you! This works great. I appreciate all of your efforts!